# SQL SUBSTRING function doesn't work properly when using CHARINDEX function to locate ']' character. why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to create bulk import sql script and I have a problem when using ']' with SUBSTRING function. the script doesn't return output as expected

```
Declare @List nvarchar(MAX) = '[Mohammed-Alkronz:7722],[Alex-John:4233],[Maria-Jose:5567]';
Declare @StartIndex int = CHARINDEX('[',@List) + 1;
Declare @LastIndex int = CHARINDEX(']',@List) - 1;
Declare @ListLen int = LEN(@List);
Declare @Delimeter int = CHARINDEX(',',@List);
Declare @record nvarchar(160);
Declare @FirstName nvarchar(50);
Declare @LastName nvarchar(50);
Declare @Extension nvarchar(50);
while(@Delimeter <> 0)
    BEGIN
        set @record = SUBSTRING(@List,@StartIndex,@LastIndex);
        set @FirstName = SUBSTRING(@record,1,CHARINDEX('-',@record)-1);
        set @LastName = SUBSTRING(@record,CHARINDEX('-',@record)+1,CHARINDEX(':',@record)-1);
        print CHARINDEX(':',@record)-1;
        set @Extension = SUBSTRING(@record,CHARINDEX(':',@record)+1,@LastIndex);
        print CHARINDEX(':',@record)+1;
        INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@Extension);

        set @List = SUBSTRING(@List,@Delimeter+1,@ListLen);
        set @StartIndex = CHARINDEX('[',@List) + 1;
        set @LastIndex = CHARINDEX(']',@List) - 1;
        set @ListLen = LEN(@List);
        set @Delimeter = CHARINDEX(',',@List);

END

    set @record = SUBSTRING(@List,@StartIndex,@LastIndex);
    set @FirstName = SUBSTRING(@record,1,CHARINDEX('-',@record)-1);
    set @LastName = SUBSTRING(@record,CHARINDEX('-',@record)+1,CHARINDEX(':',@record)-1);
    set @Extension = SUBSTRING(@record,CHARINDEX(':',@record)+1,@LastIndex);
    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@Extension);
```

select * from Employee

```
FirstName  LastName     Extension
---------- -------------- -------------
Mohammed   Alkronz:7722   7722
Alex       John:4233      4233
Maria      Jose:5567      5567
```

I'm expecting to get result like this:

```
FirstName  LastName     Extension
---------- -------------- -------------
Mohammed   Alkronz        7722
Alex       John           4233
Maria      Jose           5567
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest switching to a set based method first, a `WHILE`is a terrible solution here.

Firstly, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the values. Then you can use `TRIM` to remove the leading/trailing brackets (`[]`).

Then you can use a mix of `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING` and `STUFF`, all with `CHARINDEX` to retain/remove the needed characters:

```sql
DECLARE @List nvarchar(MAX) = '[Mohammed-Alkronz:7722],[Alex-John:4233],[Maria-Jose:5567]';

SELECT LEFT(V.Trimmed,CHARINDEX('-',V.Trimmed)-1) AS Forename,
       SUBSTRING(V.Trimmed, CHARINDEX('-',V.Trimmed) + 1, CHARINDEX(':',V.Trimmed) - CHARINDEX('-',V.Trimmed) - 1) AS Surname,
       STUFF(V.Trimmed, 1, CHARINDEX(':',V.Trimmed), N'') AS Extension
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List,',') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRIM('[]' FROM SS.[value])))V(Trimmed);
```

This does assume all your data is in the format `Forename-Surname:Extension`. If any part of the format is missing, it will error.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, but i need to insert these records into Employee table in the DB. this table has foreign key constraint with other tables so dropping the table and using SELECT INTO is not practical. any hint here?

Comment: I don't follow, you can easily prefix the above with an `INSERT`, @MoeKronz .

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Larnu, looping and string interpolation are both terrible things to try to do in SQL Server. Since you're on SQL Server 2017, another set-based approach is to manipulate your data just slightly to conform to JSON:

```
DECLARE @List nvarchar(max) = N'[Mohammed-Alkronz:7722],'
                            + N'[Alex-John:4233],[Maria-Jose:5567]';

;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT v = j1.value, j2.* FROM 
  OPENJSON('[' + TRANSLATE(@List, '[]-', '"":') + ']') AS j1
  CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(value,':','","') + '"]') AS j2
)
SELECT FirstName = [0], LastName = [1], Extension = [2]
  FROM src 
  PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [key] IN ([0],[1],[2])) AS p;
```

Output:

| FirstName | LastName | Extension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | John | 4233 |
| Maria | Jose | 5567 |
| Mohammed | Alkronz | 7722 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53e887239acb9965151d736b8c1a2857)

And if you want the output to reflect the original order of the strings:

```
DECLARE @List nvarchar(max) = N'[Mohammed-Alkronz:7722],'
                            + N'[Alex-John:4233],[Maria-Jose:5567]';

;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT v = j1.value, k = j1.[key], j2.* FROM 
-----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  OPENJSON('[' + TRANSLATE(@List, '[]-', '"":') + ']') AS j1
  CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(value,':','","') + '"]') AS j2
)
SELECT FirstName = [0], LastName = [1], Extension = [2]
  FROM src 
  PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [key] IN ([0],[1],[2])) AS p
  ORDER BY k;
--^^^^^^^^^^
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8bd0658e264344c65f17899283f38c6)